# Animation(custom animation) is not working in sidenav control

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I exactly don't know if I make mistake anywhere. 
I have two *ngFor list and a sidenav control.

I'm using angular2 sample demo given at official website (https://angular.io/api/animations/query) about animation which is working fine inside or outside of `sidenav control(angular-material)`.
BUT when I use my custom animation, it is working fine outside of sidenav control but it doesn't work inside of sidenav control.

***Note: for brevity, I have removed unnecessary code of sidenav control***

**https://plnkr.co/edit/pbW2BpMzQzFe792DTUwv?p=preview** 
(Note: if you look at this plunker, you will easily come to know where the problem. last ngFor list should work which is not working. **All ngFor are kept in the same page**.

```
animations: [

    //MY CUSTOM ANIMATION        

    trigger('myAnimation', [

      transition('*=>*',[
            query(':enter',style({opacity:0}),{optional:true}),

            query(':enter',stagger('300ms',[
              animate('1s',keyframes([
                style({opacity:0,transform:'translateY(-20px)',offset:0}),
                style({opacity:.5,transform:'translateY(20px)',offset:0.3}),
                style({opacity:0,transform:'translateY(0)',offset:1}),
              ]))
            ]),{optional:true} 
          )
      ])

   ]),

   //DEMO ANIMATION AVAILABLE AT ANGULAR.IO

   trigger('queryAnimation', [
     transition('* => goAnimate', [
       // hide the inner elements
       query('h1', style({ opacity: 0 })),
       query('.content', style({ opacity: 0 })),

       // animate the inner elements in, one by one
       query('h1', animate(2000, style({ opacity: 1, background:'yellow' })),
       query('.content', animate(3000, style({ opacity: 1, background:'red' })),
     ])
   ])
  ]
```

Problem seems to be very simple but I'm unable to figure it out. Help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: somebody please help. my all components are within sidenav control and animation is not working for some reason within sidenav.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the `div` element with your animation entering the HTML DOM at the same time as its children, so they don't get animated - the `:enter` event doesn't happen. To get around it, you can assign the `items` array asynchronously ([plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/S1P1y9J8JMkaUY6X9IOC?p=preview)):

```
this.items=[];
setTimeout(() => {
  this.items=[{Id:1,name:"Nyks1"},{Id:2,name:"Nyks2"},{Id:3,name:"Nyks3"}];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I appreciate your answer but the question is why it is working for demo sample code and not for my code? both are almost equal.